# how to automatically rename a sheetname in a for loop (xlsx)

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to construct a loop which automatically subsets a dataset, makes alot of computations, and prints the results for each group as seperate sheets to a xlsx-workbook-file. It should work along the lines of the following code:

```
library(xlsx)
clist <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")
for (i in clist) {
datasubset <- filter(data, group == i)

mean <- mean(datasubset)

results <- createWorkbook()
sheet.i <- createSheet(results, sheetName = paste("results", i, sep=" "))
addDataFrame(mean, sheet.i, startRow=1, startColumn=1, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

the last 2 lines obviously dont work. The question is how do I get the sheet.i to be named according to value of i. so for instance: sheet.group1, sheet.group2, etc. So with what code should "sheet.i" be substituted with? or is there another way to achieve my goal within a different package or a different approach?

Comment: Would you consider a solution that uses VBA to construct the workbook?

Comment: You should post the `library(.)` call to the XL-R connection package you are using. Seems as though there should be somes sort of addWorkSheet function. Have you looked at the help page for the package you are using?

Comment: @BondedDust you are right, sry, added the library, I am also open to other solutions, dsnt have to be using the xlsx package the important part is exporting the results into excel so i can send them to my boss because there are a lot of computations going on inside the loop function, what help page are you talking about? the documentation? if so yes, found nothing

Comment: @vpipkt I have no idea how VBA works,sry, but thanks!

Comment: Strange, .... When I look at the `Worksheet` help page linked from the `help(pack=xlsx)` help page, I see `createSheet` describes.

Comment: what i am saying is: yes i read it, but found nothing which helped, otherwise i wouldnt have posted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot's of things need fixing in the above code for this to work but I hope this will help solve them:

```
library(xlsx)
x <- runif(900)
group <- rep(c('group1','group2','group3'),300)
df <- data.frame(x,group)

wb <- createWorkbook() #make workbook outside the loop. You only need 1 workbook
for ( i in c('group1','group2','group3')) {
  datasubset <- subset(df, group == i)

  mean <- data.frame(mean(datasubset[['x']])) #needs to be a dataframe to use addDataFrame

  sheet <- createSheet(wb , sheetName = sprintf('sheet.%s',i)) #make each sheet

  addDataFrame(mean, sheet, startRow=1, startColumn=1, row.names = FALSE) #add dataframe 'mean' to each sheet
}
saveWorkbook(wb, 'test.xlsx') #don't forget to save
```

and you got your excel with all your sheets!

This is my output:

[image]

Comment: I tried pretty much the same thing which doesnt work, and yes my above code is imcomplete, i just wanted to show how the problem works, the problem with your code is that it overwrites the sheet and does NOT create a new sheet each time, so there are not multiple sheets inside the workbook but just the data of the last run through the loop, so group3 in this case

Comment: I got it to work, you just need to add rm(sheet) at the end of each run through the loop, so it deletes the sheet and then it works, finally, I edited your code by adding rm(sheet) at the end

Comment: rm() is redundant as it just removes the variable at each loop. this happens anyways as the variable gets overwritten. As you can see the code works without rm().

Comment: you are right, just got it to work without rm() as well. Thanks alot! so basically my mistake was doing `(i in clist)` instead of your `for ( i in c('group1','group2','group3'))`, because the rest is equivalent with the code i used , except the `sprintf` but using `paste` should work the same and creating the workbook inside the loop, right? I just wanna learn from my mistakes, so thanks for any hints and answers,

Comment: No worries :) I am really happy I was able to help. Using paste should be fine as well but don't create the Workbook inside the loop as it will be overwritten every time and you will end up with only the last sheet at the end. That's the correct attitude you have! we all need to learn from our mistakes.

Comment: aah you are right, thanks alot for the kindness and all the friendly and helpful answers, learned a lot from you!